# Python: Web2py error handling

Tags: python, web2py

I am using [`web2py`](http://www.web2py.com/) as my python framework. I am having problem in redirecting/routing pages.

Scenario is for example, when I am going to this URL:

```
www.example/web2pyApplication/controller
```

Then accidentally change the URL to this:

```
www.example/web2pyApplication/controller1
```

The error that gets displayed will be:

```
invalid controller (controller1/index)
```

Is there a way to catch and handle the error, so that it redirects to a 404 page instead?

Comment: check this link : http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Routes-on-error

Answer (score 2):

There are two options, both explained in the [Routes on error](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Routes-on-error) section of the book.

First, you can customize the error message displayed when an invalid app, controller, or function is called by setting `error_message`.

Second, you can set `routes_onerror`:

```
routes_onerror = [
  ('myapp/404', '/myapp/static/cantfind.html')
]
```

Note, the error handler URL does not have to be a static page but can instead be another web2py action (preferably in a different app).

Comment: Did you either restart the server or reload routes (which can be done via the admin interface)?